# Location of bind-mount volume provided in docker-compose file of mongodb

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, persistent-volumes

How to see the location of bind-mount volume provided in the docker-compose yml file. I have created an bind-mount to persist the mongodb.
It is working fine i.e. if container is shut, then also the data is present, but I want to know where is this location present in my computer.

```
version : "3"
services:
eswmongodb:
  image: mongo:latest
  container_name: mongocont
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
  volumes:
    - "~/mongo/db:/data/db"
```

Comment: It should be in the location specified in the first half of `volumes:`; if it's a relative path, it will be relative to the location of the `docker-compose.yml` file.  In the case of database storage there's not usually a lot you can do with the opaque binary database files but you should be able to at least see them.

Comment: @DavidMaze, yes I have given them but don't know where to see them.

Answer (score 2):

> if the container is shut, the data is present

There would be no way for you to know this unless you've already found it stored on the host.

The location is what you've given - `~/mongo/db`. Open a terminal and `cd` to the path

Keep in mind that in Windows, `~` is a special character and is sometimes hidden in the file explorer. If you're using it to get to your User folder, you should prefer using environment variables instead https://superuser.com/questions/332871/what-is-the-equivalent-of-linuxs-tilde-in-windows

Comment: I am using a mac

Comment: In that case, `~` is your Users folder